# Cannot seem to use a type expression with a type variable in an instance declaration with a function needing an explicit type

Tags: haskell, type-variables

I cannot find anyway in Haskell to specify the type of the call to '**neg**':

```
instance Arith (V3 e) where neg x = vfmap (neg :: e->e)  x
```

**(V3 e)** and **e** are both instances of **Arith**.  Here I want to call the '**neg**' already defined for the type **'e'**.  But this requires an explicit type on the '**neg**' call and no expression can resolve the type?  If use a specific instance of **'e'**, it si fine.

`vfmap (neg :: Dist->Dist ) x`  -- this works (but is not general enough)
`vfmap (neg :: e->e) x` --  No instance for (**Arith e1**) arising from a use of **‘neg**’ 
`vfmap neg e` -- Ambiguous type variable ‘e0’ arising from a use of ‘neg’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Arith e0)’ from being solved.
`vfmap (neg :: Arith e => e->e) x` -- ditto

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, InstanceSigs #-}
data Dist = Inch Float deriving (Show)

class Arith a where
   neg :: a->a

instance Arith Dist where
   neg (Inch x) = Inch (-x)

data V2 e = V2 e e    deriving (Show) 
data V3 e = V3 e e e  deriving (Show)

class VMap c e where
   vfmap :: (e->e)->c->c

instance VMap (V2 e) e where
   vfmap f (V2 x1 x2) = V2 (f x1) (f x2)
instance VMap (V3 e) e where
   vfmap f (V3 x1 x2 x3) = V3 (f x1) (f x2) (f x3)

-- 2 & 3 point vectors should also be Arith
instance Arith (V2 Dist) where 
   neg x = vfmap (neg :: Dist->Dist) x -- works, but must have type on neg

instance Arith (V3 e) where 
   neg x = vfmap (neg :: Arith e => e->e)  x -- nothing here seems to work
```

**vfmap** can be applied to a (**V2 e**) or a (**V3 e**), either vector type for a vector of any **Arith** element type.

This won't seem to compile when the element type is a type variable, e.g.

• Ambiguous type variable ‘**e0**’ arising from an expression type signature
      prevents the constraint ‘**(Arith e0)**’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘**e0**’ should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that in Haskell, type variables aren't scoped: that is, if you define `instance Arith (V3 e)`, you can't use `e` inside the instance; if you try to, GHC will interpret it as being a completely separate type variable. Luckily, you can use `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` to enable scoped type variables. If you do that, you'll also find you need to add an extra `Arith e =>` constraint; adding this will allow it to compile successfully.

(Aside: when dealing with `MultiParamTypeClasses`, `{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}` is also incredibly useful; I would personally use it in a case like this, as it removes the need for explicit type declarations for `neg`. The idea is that you define instead `class Functor c e | c -> e`, which basically means that the type for `c` determines the type for `e` as well. I won't describe it here, but I would **highly** encourage you to look it up.)

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  I appreciate your understanding my problem and giving constructive feedback.

The real solution here was "class Functor c e | c -> e".

For reference, I was not actually trying to use a scoped type variable.  I am used to do being able to do so from a C++ background, where you can connect the element and collection of element type directly.  So, Haskell left me confused.

Comment: @ErvanDarnell You're very welcome. (Also, if my answer solved your problem, could you accept it? Once it's accepted this question is marked as 'solved'.)